# Hough Transform not working to recognize a line

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, hough-transform

I have an image composed of small white dots that should stay on the same line.

[image]

I wanted to recognize this line using the Hough Transform. To do that I binarized the image, calculated the centroid of each dot and therefore I got an image that is all black except a few white pixels in the position of the centroids of the original dots.

[image]

Then I applied the hough transform algorithm (already implemented in Matlab), but it looks not capable to fully detect this line. In particular it skips the last dot in the bottom.

[image]

Do you know why this is happening? I would like to understand why the hough trasform method is not working properly and if there is any kind of improvement I can apply.

Here is my Matlab code:

```
BW = imbinarize(data,0.04);

s = regionprops(BW,'centroid');
centroids = cat(1, s.Centroid);
imshow(BW)
hold on
plot(centroids(:,1),centroids(:,2), 'r*')
BW(:,:)=0;
for k=1:size(centroids,1)
    BW(round(centroids(k,2)),round(centroids(k,1)))=1;
end

[H,T,R] = hough(BW,'RhoResolution',0.1,'Theta',-90:1:89.9);
P  = houghpeaks(H,5,'Theta',T,'threshold',ceil(0.3*max(H(:))));
lines = houghlines(BW,T,R,P,'FillGap',10000,'MinLength',1);
figure, imshow(BW), hold on
max_len = 0;
for k = 1:length(lines)
xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green'); 

plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');

len = norm(lines(k).point1 - lines(k).point2);
if ( len > max_len)
   max_len = len;
   xy_long = xy;
end
end
plot(xy_long(:,1),xy_long(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','cyan');
```

Comment: I don't see a line when I see three dots. *You* interpret that there is a line!

Comment: @MarcusMüller the dots are more than three, if you enlarge the image or binarize it's easier to tell. I *know* for sure that these dots should stay on the same line because I know the physics of the system that gave origin of these dots.

Comment: Yeah, but the fact that they are *on a line* doesn't mean there *is a line*!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I edited the question. You will see that the problem is not the fact that these points are disconnected, but the fact that that I use the centroids, somehow.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm sorry Marcus, but I'm not understanding. Could you please explain why my algorithm is not working, in detail, and how should I correct it to make it work?

Comment: Why are you trying to detect a line, when there's no line?

Comment: @MarcusMüller A line is a set of points in a plane with the well know relationship $y=mx +q$. The points in my image satisfy this definition, so there is a line.

Comment: A line is the **whole** set of points that fulfill that relationship. Your couple of centroids are *part* of that set, but not a line by themselves; Hough estimates get wildly random and inefficient when you have lines that aren't represented by a solid amount of the full set. What you want is probably classical PCA, not image processing! So, your Hough algorithm works as expected on this kind of data: badly. It's the wrong approach, but the right one is actually easier and faster :)

Comment: wait, even PCA would be over the top. What you want is a linear function fit to the $(x,y)$ data you've got in shape of the positions of those centroids.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is just to find the function

$$y(x) = mx + q$$

that fits through the centroids you've found.

You wouldn't do a Hough transform on that (since Hough transforms generally perform badly in presence of only few representatives of the full line, and are pretty computationally intense), but simply look for something like the least squared error fit of a $y(x)$ through the $(x_i, y_i)$ tuples given by the coordinates of your centroids.

Comment: Yes, what I already did is exactly a linear fit of the coordinates of these centroids. My question was not about finding an alternative method to the hough transform, but I wanted to understand why the hough trasform method was not working, if there is any kind of improvement I can apply and why there is a difference why I apply it on the simply binarized image and when I apply it with the image with the centroids.

Comment: Well, it doesn't perform well because it's designed to do something different than what you're trying to make it do. There really is only a hint of a line, not a line in your image.

Comment: Could you please explain this better? If my understanding of the math behind the Hough trasform is correct if I have no other signal in my image except my 5 points even if the peaks in the $\rho\theta$ space will be dim they will still be very well recognizable, because there is no noise at all to cover the signal of my line.

Comment: well, good key word: in your $(\rho, \theta)$ space, the upper four points fall onto one point – and everything is fine; however, the last centroid is offset enough from the theoretical line you're looking for that all connections between that centroid and any other centroid maps to a significantly different point in the $(\rho, \theta)$ plane. Hence, there's not enough power accumulating in these four accumulator space points individually for the Hough algorithm you're using to detect a peak.

Comment: So, the problem is that the Hough Transform is not able to deal with unprecise alignment of the points and it is expected to detect only *ideal* lines?

Comment: well, yes/no! When you've actually got a *line*, not just two points on a line, the fact that many pixels map onto the same $\rho, \theta$ makes it very robust. If you only got single pixels on each end of a line, there's nothing to accumulate, and yes, then it can only work on exact lines.

Comment: Nice, I'm starting to understand. If you move this explanation in detail from the commens to the main answer I will give you the right answer tag :)